# How to open file by default application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to open pdf file by default pdf viewer xamarin forms, but I get exception:

> Android.OS.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///storage/emulated/0/pdfy/pdfik.pdf exposed beyond app through
>   Intent.getData()

I added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, and this:

```
    while (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
    }
    while (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage}, 0);
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to open file:

```
 public bool OpenFile(string filename)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(filename));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl((string)uri).ToLower());
                intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);

                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

                try
                {
                    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                    //ApplicationContext.StartActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, "No Application Available to View this file", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    //Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "No Application Available to View this file", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using FileProvider for the PDF path:

```
Android.Net.Uri pdfPath = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, "com.mydomain.fileprovider", new Java.IO.File(filePath));
```

Find an example here: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/130